# How to interact with JHipster context in blueprints

Tags: jhipster, code-generation, yeoman

I'm new in JHipster, but I already have a task - to make a blueprint for an Angular client side change with jhipster-generator (by `npx jhipster generate-blueprint`)

What I did:

1. Generated non-local blueprint
2. Copy angular folder from `node_modules/generator-jhipster`. So, structure is follow:

[structure of blueprint project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyK0n.png)

3. Injected a new markup
4. Created "`npm link`"
5. Generate project connected to this blueprint.

Package-json of blueprint:
[package.json of blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX2Ok.png)

1. I edited template file of Angular, added this to files in generator.mjs:

   ```
   get [AngularGenerator.WRITING]() {
       return this.asWritingTaskGroup({
         ...super.writing,
         async writingTemplateTask({ application }) {
           await this.writeFiles({
             sections: {
               files: [{ templates: ['/src/main/webapp/app/entities/_entityFolder/list/_entityFile.component.html.ejs'] }],
             },
             context: application,
           });
     },
   });
   ```

   }

My problem:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1y0N.png)

How to inject in my project Jhipster context? All variables, as I understand it, can be taken from the JHipster context.  Also, I want to add new functionality, that is, also expand the context.  How to interact with the context?  Thanks for the answer